# Performing Statistics Functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I'm trying to perform statistical functions in VBA but I've run into a wall. I have everything set up as you can see. The average function works fine but the others are failing. Any help would be amazing!

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim Counter As Integer
 Dim Count
 Dim Total As Integer
 Dim Average As Integer
 Dim Std_Dev As Integer
 Dim Max As Integer
 Dim Min As Integer
 Dim Median As Integer

 With ListBox1
     For Counter = 0 To .ListCount - 1

         If .Selected(Counter) Then
             Count = Count + 1
             Total = Total + .List(Counter)
         End If
     Next Counter
 End With

 Average = (Total / Count)
 'Std_Dev = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S()
 Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ListBox1.ListCount)
 'Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min()
 'Median = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median()

 Unload Me
 MsgBox "Test. " & Std_Dev
 End Sub

 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Unload Me
 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Click()

 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 For Each cell In Range("Scores")
     ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
 Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to carefully read the MSDN help topics (for instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838412.aspx) and you'll find that:

- those functions outputs `Double` data type values
- they need arguments to be filled...

so the following could be a possible code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Counter As Integer, selectedCounter As Integer
Dim Total As Double, Average As Double, Std_Dev As Double, Max As Double, Min As Double, Median As Double '<== use "Double" data type, since this is the return value of those functions
Dim numArr() As Integer '<== use an array to store selected items

With Me.ListBox1
    ReDim numArr(1 To .ListCount) As Integer '<== dim array to its maximum possible size
    For Counter = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(Counter) Then
            selectedCounter = selectedCounter + 1
            numArr(selectedCounter) = .List(Counter)
        End If
    Next Counter
End With
ReDim Preserve numArr(1 To selectedCounter) As Integer '<== redim array to its actual size

Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(numArr)
Average = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(numArr)
Std_Dev = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(numArr)
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(numArr)
Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(numArr)
Median = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(numArr)

Unload Me

MsgBox "Test Results:" & vbCrLf _
        & vbCrLf & "Total: " & Total _
        & vbCrLf & "Average: " & Average _
        & vbCrLf & "Std_Dev: " & Std_Dev _
        & vbCrLf & "Max: " & Max _
        & vbCrLf & "Min: " & Min _
        & vbCrLf & "Median: " & Median

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range

'Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Range("Scores")) '<== consider this if "Scores" is a one-column range
For Each cell In Range("Scores")
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I worked on this for 6+ hours and couldn't figure it out. You literally are a life saver!